# Showing E to be a sigma algebra on X

Tags: measure-theory

I'm trying to learn how to prove a collection of sets is a sigma algebra. I'm trying to solve a problem in my textbook, but it's been a long time since I've used math so I'm having a bit of trouble.
It goes:

Let $X$ be a non-empty set and let $B$ be a subset of $X$. Show that

$ \epsilon_B := \{ A \subseteq X : B \subseteq A \ \text{or} \ B \subseteq A^c \} $

is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$.

So I know I have to show 3 conditions:

(1) $X \in \epsilon_B $

$A \cup A^c = X$ and since $B$ can be in either $A$ or $A^c$ we must have that $X \in \epsilon_B $ .

(2) If $B \in \epsilon_B$ then $B^c \in \epsilon_B$.

$B \subseteq A \Rightarrow B^c \subseteq A^c$. We now from (1) that $A^c \in X \in \epsilon_B$ then $B^c$ must be in $\epsilon_B$ as well.

(3) The union of $B_n$ is in $\epsilon_B$

$( \cup_{i \in I} B_i) \cap B_i^c = \cup_{i \in I} (B_i \cap B_i^c) = \emptyset $

Which is in $\epsilon_B$ since $X \in \epsilon_B \Rightarrow \emptyset \in \epsilon_B$.

Any help that can point me in the right direction is greatly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be misunderstanding the role of $A$ in the definition of $\epsilon _B$.  $\{A \subset X\; : \ldots\}$ means "the set of subsets of $X$ such that....

So for (1), you have to show that $X$ is a subset of $X$ such that $B \subseteq X$ or $B \subseteq X^c$.  This is true because any set is a subset of itself, and by assumption $B$ is a subset of $X$.

For (2), you should use a a different letter than $B$, which is already in use.  The condition (2) is that for all $A \in \epsilon_B$, $A^c \in \epsilon_B$.  This is true because $A = (A^c)^c$, so either  or $B \subseteq A^c$ or $B \subseteq A = (A^c)^c$.

For (3) you want to show that if you have a sequence $A_i$ of members of $\epsilon_B$, then $\bigcup_{i} A_i$ (let's call it $U$) is in $\epsilon_B$.
Either there is some $A_i$ such that $B \subseteq A_i$, in which case 
$B \subseteq U$, or for every $A_i$ we have $B \subseteq A_i^c$, in which case
$B \subseteq \bigcap_i A_i^c = U^c$.